# what are the maven dependencies for Java 8 and Servlet 4?

Tags: jakarta-ee, java-8, servlet-4

I need versions for all jars servlet-api. jsp-api, el-api, jstl., etc// where and How to find these information?

Answer (score 0):

you could find all information regarding lib and versions on [maven repository](https://mvnrepository.com/https://)